# ng jsTree returning wrong object as selected nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree

I am working with ng jsTree component https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree

Here is my implementation

```
<div js-tree="treeConfig" ng-model="treeData" tree="treeInstance" tree-events="check_node:getSelectedCategories;uncheck_node:getSelectedCategories"></div>
```

JS code in controller

```
$scope.treeConfig = {
    core : {
        multiple : true,
        animation: false,
        error : function(error) {
            $log.error('treeCtrl: error from js tree - ' + angular.toJson(error));
        },
        check_callback : true,
        worker : true
    },
    types : {
        default : {
            icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-flash'
        },
        star : {
            icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-star'
        },
        cloud : {
            icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud'
        }
    },
    version : 1,
    "checkbox" : {
        "tie_selection" : false
    },
    plugins : ['types','checkbox']
};

$scope.treeData = [
    { id : 'ajson1', parent : '#', text : 'Simple root node', state: { opened: true} },
    { id : 'ajson2', parent : '#', text : 'Root node 2', state: { opened: true} },
    { id : 'ajson3', parent : 'ajson2', text : 'Child 1', state: { opened: true} },
    { id : 'ajson4', parent : 'ajson2', text : 'Child 2' , state: { opened: true}}
];

$scope.getSelectedCategories = function(e, data) {
    console.log('data: ', data);
};
```

So, when I check 'ajson2' node, data returned with selected attribute is 'ajson2', but when I uncheck 'ajson2', data returned with selected attribute is 'ajson3', 'ajson4'.

Looks like this is bug, or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console logging 'data' was not giving correct information.

Just figured out solution. updated $scope.getSelectedCategories() as follows

```
$scope.getSelectedCategories = function() {
    var selected_nodes = $scope.treeInstance.jstree(true).get_checked(true);
    console.log(selected_nodes);
};
```

which logs selected node object/s.